# How to Eval a SQL timestamp?

Tags: c#, asp.net, eval

I am having a repeater control and I want it to be displayed in side a label in the repeater control. How do I do that ? For now it is printing blank characters instead of the time ? any ideas ?

The label I have looks like this ;

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# (Eval("QTime"))%> '></asp:Label>
```

this is giving me an output like ""AAAAAAAALuE=". I think a conversion is needed here , and I want to know how to do that say using a helper function or something.

NOTE: The timestamp is coming from MS SQL Database field "timestamp"

thanks

Comment: Where is this timestamp coming from? What data type is it? Why do you need to `Eval` it?

Comment: Which DBMS, timestamp means different things. In sql server it isn't a time....

Comment: Do you mean the `timestamp` datatype from SQL Server?

Answer (score 1):

You can't get a `DateTime` from a `TIMESTAMP` column on SQL Server.

From MSDN - [timestamp (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx):

> Is a data type that exposes automatically generated, unique binary numbers within a database. rowversion is generally used as a mechanism for version-stamping table rows.

This type was renamed to `rowversion` in version later than SQL Server 2005 exactly because of this kind of confusion.

`timestamp`/`rowversion` are simply ways to tell whether the row data has changed - they do not have any relation to the date or time.

You need to use a `DateTime` data type instead.

Comment: @ShaneAdrianMuaz - You need to record such things yourself in a `DATETIME` column.

Comment: Astonishing how many people never read the documentation. This is a repeating question - asked about once per week here, if If remember right, and personally one of my questions I use to filter out incompetents when looking for SQL Server developers - sadly with a significant degree ;) It is VERY clear in the documentation.

Comment: @TomTom - Agreed. The documentation even says: `To record a date or time, use a datetime2 data type`...

Comment: @ShaneAdrianMuaz - No. You can write an `insert/update` trigger on each table that will do that.

Comment: @ShaneAdrianMuaz - This is not a forum. It is a question and answer site. And we do expect people to at least do _some_ research. There was a list of questions that came up when you wrote the title to this one. I bet you didn't even look at a single one of those.

Comment: @Oded You are making judgments based on assumptions! And "question and answer site" is a good way to put it :P

Comment: @ShaneAdrianMuaz - What assumptions have I made? I explained what people who are regulars here expect.

Comment: @ShaneAdrianMuaz - Calm down. Again, you say I am making assumptions. I said nothing about you or the question. I actually answered it. I am happy to delete my answer if it offends you so much.

Comment: Lets keep comments constructive, please. If you want to have an extended discussion, please move it to chat.